# Does there exist a unique decomposition of maps from sphere to itself, with respect to degree of the map?

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology

In topology, the degree of a map is a homotopy invariant and degree is an isomorphism between $[S^n,S^n]=\pi_nS^n$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. As degree of a map admits the multiplicative property of deg($f\circ g$)=deg$f$deg$g$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ admits the unique prime factorization, does there somehow exist 'prime maps' $[p]\in[S^n,S^n]$,s.t. given a map $f$ of degree $d=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}$, $f$ can be uniquely decomposed by compositions of 'prime maps'?

Comment: Trivially yes. Since there exists an isomorphism $h : [S^n,S^n] \to \mathbb Z$, take the preimages $h^{-1}(p)$ of the prime elements $p$ of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you so much!